# nginx stuck and setting CLOSE_WAIT when using worker_processes > 1

Tags: nginx, tcp

Everything works nicely if I have worker_processes=1, or I run one request at a time.
If I open a browser on a fresh nginx install and holds F5 down a couple of seconds, the sockets gets lingering as CLOSE_WAIT, and nginx wont do anything (other than stuffing more sockets in CLOSE_WAIT..)

The more workers I use, the sooner it gets stuck. Just one of the workers has listed any sockets though..

Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Stuck means it won't answer any more requests?  Is this CLOSE_WAIT on the client or the upstream?  Does the error_log say anything?  Can you include tcpdump output of a failed request?

Comment: Your talking latin.. After a request has become CLOSE_WAIT, any subsequent request also becomes CLOSE_WAIT. No errors are showing in the logs. I'm on windows - could you explain how to do an tcpdump? (Whats the tool called in windows?)

Comment: Wireshark makes a windows version: http://www.wireshark.org/download.html

Comment: Damn wireshark seems complex. It doesn't seem like it listens on local-only sockets